# Mobile Data Usage gets enabled automatically

Tags: 8.1, settings, nokia-lumia-535, cellular-data

Lumia 535 Dual-SIM, Windows Phone 8.1, OS Version 8.10.14234.375.

I have noticed that infrequently my mobile data gets enabled automatically even when I had turned it off earlier.

In Store and Feedback I have set to WiFi-only. Is there anything else I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Settings* -> *mobile+SIM* or *cellular+SIM* for some users as noted in comments.

Change the option "For limited Wi-Fi connectivity" to "don't use mobile data" from "use mobile data".

[image: mobile+SIM setting in WP8.1]

Comment: In my phone there is no setting as `mobile+SIM` but as `cellular+SIM` I wonder how come it differed unless you have different OS and Model. Anyway Thank You! :)

Comment: I think it depends on your regional settings. It should be "mobile + SIM" for British English and "cellular + SIM" for American English.