# Bluetooth gets enabled automatically

Tags: nokia-lumia-535

Not quite often but sometimes I could see my Bluetooth gets enabled automatically without I being enabling it.

I got myself into similar issue but got itself resolved it here: [Mobile Data Usage gets enabled automatically](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/12605/mobile-data-usage-gets-enabled-automatically)

Thank you,